# Interfacing with iPhone/Android Music Playing over bluetooth with Pebble

Tags: c, audio-player, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I would like to create a simple Pebble watchapp that can play/pause and skip songs that are currently playing on the phone, similar to the built-in app.

I have never created a watchapp, but I have done the Hello World official example app.

I don't really know where to start, as I haven't found much in the way of documentation as far as interfacing with the phone. I do not want my app to require a companion app.

The pebble documentation is short at best, and doesn't (AFAICS) contain relevant information. 
https://developer.getpebble.com/2/api-reference/

Where could I go about finding the information on how to interface with the phone's music control without a companion app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control the music player from a Pebble app running on the watch.

What others have done in the past (See [peapod on github](https://github.com/Katharine/peapod)) is write a Pebble app that talks to an iOS companion app with appmessage. The iOS companion app controls the music player.

Comment: How do other accessories implement the play/pause/skip buttons without an app then? (ie bluetooth dock or headphones)

Comment: Bluetooth accessories use the AVRCP protocol that is part of the Bluetooth stack. Pebble uses that too in the official "Music" application on your Pebble but this is not available to 3rd party apps.